# Sencha production build cache issue

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-cmd5

This was issue i'm facing [check this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194928-Can-t-update-a-production-build).
I'm trying to update the existing app with same signed apk key by below command

```
cordova run android --debug -- --keystore="keystore" --storePassword="pass" --alias="aliasname" --password="pass"
```

on above command. The app is getting updated but build gets break.

**production.default.properties**

```
build.options.logger=no

build.options.debug=false

enable.deltas=false

enable.cache.manifest=true  

enable.resource.compression=true

app.microloader.name=production.js

build.embedded.microloader.compressor=-closure

# enable the full class system optimizer
app.output.js.optimize=true
build.optimize=${build.optimize.enable}
```

The application is not getting updated.

Comment: I can only recommend that you change your workflow and write a batch file that first compiles the extjs code using sencha command, then copies over the files into the cordova project, and then creates the app using original cordova commands. That's what I did after the third time the cordova and sencha cmd versions did not work together, and when my build process broke afterwards, it was far easier to pinpoint down the problem.

Comment: Exactly same issue i'm facing https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194928-Can-t-update-a-production-build